No me funciona live Server
quería ver si me pueden ayudar :/ uso live server para visualizar los cambios de las páginas, pero ya no me funciona, no se me actualiza la página, pero al lanzar el server si lo hace, el autoguardado también lo tengo activo y pues lo único es que debo de recargar la página para que se muestre el cambio, saben cómo puedo arreglarlo?

En mis proyectos tengo una estructura de carpetas más grande, carpetas dentro de carpetas y más carpetas dentro de otras y no tengo ese problema. El problema es otro, tú sientete libre de hacer las carpetas y archivos que gustes.
Lo que pasa es que debemos abrir el Live Server mientras estamos visualizando el archivo html, en tu caso index.html. Y como dijiste al inicio, si lo abres mirando el archivo CSS no funciona. Y por si a alguien le sirve: Hace poco me pasó que Live Server no recargaba automaticamente la página en el navegador (uso WSL con Ubuntu) y el problema ocurría porque yo no tení

eh encontrado la respuesta, acabo de recordar que cuando ejecuto el live server desde el archivo css de mi proyecto me lanza la pagina con las rutas de mi archivo, anexo una imagen de como deberia de verse

pero al hacerlo en el documento de mi proyecto, y en otros que tengo no me mostraba las carpetas de las rutas como la siguiente imagen:

entonces deduje que lo que hace la extension es actualizar las paginas desde la misma ruta de archivos, por lo tanto intente solucionar esto y lo consegui.
Solucion:
para arreglarlo solo tuve que mover la carpeta de mi proyecto, porque la carpeta que tenia en vsc para mis proyectos era una carpeta anidada divida por cursos y materias:

y mejor añadi las carpetas de los archivos que si necesitaria y elimine lo que no, me quedo la siguiente ruta:

asi que basicamente solo debes de evitar poner muchos archivos dentro de otros para que funcione bien.
espero que sea entendible y que les sirva, muchas gracias ^u^
